# Is it possible to use selenium-webdriver with Vue.js in Browser javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, vue.js, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use selenium-webdriver in Browser javascript.

I mean, I had installed chromedriver in my local machine, and I want to develop a web app with Vue.js, when loading a web page, a function will call chromedriver with selenium-webdriver.

Is it possible to do that ?

Or selenium-webdriver only supports a backend or command line javascript application running on nodejs ?

Comment: Your best bet would be to create a REST interface for the scripts to execute and then call these REST endpoints in Vue.js UI, but you can still try using a remote webdriver and connecting it via browser JS

Comment: @TarunLalwani, thanks, seems remote webdriver is most close to my idea.